# Lint check for Javascript equality misused as an assignment in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

In Javascript I often make the mistake of leaving out an equal sign in comparison operations:

```
if (a = b) {
...
}
```

This really should be:

```
if (a == b) {
...
}
```

Is there a way in IntelliJ to detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling  **Result of assignment used** in **Settings | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript | Assignment issues** - it reports assignment expressions where the result of the assignment is used in a containing expression.